# Any differences between `su` vs. `su -` beside the pathing?

Tags: linux, su

I see that `su -` makes the shell a login shell from `su --help`. I'm curious what the differences are between this and a normal `su` command.

I know there seems to be a difference in the paths, any other differences or is that pretty much the only difference?

Answer (score 5):

difference i usually meet is difference in  environment variables.
su - change environment, su don't.
For example: "su -" can give different PATH, accessing other tools, Can give other HOME with different configuration ( ~/.ssh !/.Xauthority etc)

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK `su -` simulates a fresh login, so triggers everything related to logging in, while `su` simply switches the user to root.

Answer (score 2):

A login shell sources ~/.profile if it exists. Therefore, it really depends, what do you have in your ~/.profile?

Usually these are environment variable differences, such as the PATH, or the prompt (PS1 environment variable) but obviously there can be other differences.. It really depends on what you put in your shell config scripts.

Answer (score 0):

from `man su`

```
   -, -l, --login
          make the shell a login shell
```

so the next question is what is a login shell, and how it differs from a non-login shell.

In `man bash` under `INVOCATION` you can read a long and pedantic section, that boils down to something like: login shell runs the `profile` file(s) (e.g. `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile`) while the interactive non-login shell runs the `bashrc` files.